# Selecting option from dropdown through URL in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

My Website url is:

```
http://zserver.in/P178wordpress/
```

The home page has a form with two dropdown box. Now I want when the user enters url:

```
http://zserver.in/P178wordpress/removals-from-Algeria-to-Afghanistan
```

then the values in the dropdowns are auto select with Algeria and Afghanistan. As i am a newbie on wordpress so a little confused. this can be done in htaccess or javascript? Please provide me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The task you asked is not very specific about wordpress. At the code from where the html of the drop down is being generated , you can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to check the url is what and on the basis of that you can write the  Your text

Answer (score 0):

You should use php Form with GET method with two input parameters one for first country and second for the second country thang in select you can set selected in options where select option value is equal with $_GET["PARAMETER"]